# Trading API Python project: Unable to update grid text in tkinter to show that price levels have been calculated correctly

Tags: python, api, tkinter, decimal, trading

So the functionality I am currently working on is for an API trading tool that will take a high and low market price from the user and place multiple (a user defined number) stacked orders between (and including) those two price boundaries. I have made a very rough UI in tkinter and have been printing one of the calculations onto tkinter grid(row=0, column=0) to have a visual aid while using trial and error to create the order cascading algorithm.

Within the "distance" function and the if statement just below (outside of) that function, i am trying to generate a list of price levels for each order to be created within the stack, once the submit button has been clicked. However, in the else statement WITHIN distance(), it no longer seems to be showing the "splitDistance" string within tile1 when I click the submit order button. I also have a hunch that it may not be returning splitDistance to distance() when I insert a high and low price, such as "4357.9" and "4272.7", meaning the "if distance() is not None:" line would never become True.

I have not used python in a few years and am jumping straight back into it again, so I apologize if this is a nooby question / is something that has already been answered, however I haven't been able to find anything related so far.

This is my code for the UI and functionality so far. I have not started writing functionality for the right-hand side of the grid yet, but any tips or suggestions to improve my code are still appreciated.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
number = 50
tile5 = Entry(root, fg="grey")
tile5.grid(row=1, column=1)
tile5.insert(0, "HIGHEST POSITION")
tile17 = Entry(root, fg="grey")
tile17.grid(row=5, column=1)
tile17.insert(0, "LOWEST POSITION")

def tile5Faux(event):
    tile5.delete(0, "end")
    tile5['foreground'] = 'black'
    return None
tile5.bind("<FocusIn>", tile5Faux)


def tile17Faux(event):
    tile17.delete(0, "end")
    tile17['foreground'] = 'black'
    return None
tile17.bind("<FocusIn>", tile17Faux)


highPos = tile5.get()
lowPos = tile17.get()

def increment():
    global number
    number += 1
    tile12 = Label(root, text=number).grid(row=3, column=2)

def decrement():
    global number
    number -= 1
    tile12 = Label(root, text=number).grid(row=3, column=2)

def distance():
    global highPos
    global lowPos
    global number
    numberFloat = float(number)
    if (highPos == "HIGHEST POSITION") or (lowPos == "LOWEST POSITION"):
        return
    else:
        totalDistance = "{:.1f}".format(Decimal(highPos)) - (Decimal(lowPos))
        splitDistance = "{:.1f}".format(Decimal(float(totalDistance) / Decimal(numberfloat)))
        tile1 = Label(root, text=splitDistance).grid(row=0, column=0)
        return splitDistance

if distance() is not None:
    orderPositions = [ 
        highPos, 
        ]
    countUp = 2
    singleSpread = float(highPos)
    while number is not countUp:
        singleSpread -= float(distance())
        orderPositions.append(singleSpread)
        countUp += 1


tile1 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=0, column=0)
tile2 = Label(root, text="ORDER LADDER").grid(row=0, column=1)
tile3 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=0, column=2)

tile4 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=1, column=0)
tile6 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=1, column=2)

tile7 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=2, column=0)
tile8 = Button(root, text="+", command=increment).grid(row=2, column=1)
tile9 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=2, column=2)

tile10 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=3, column=0)
tile11 = Label(root, text="NUMBER OF ORDERS :").grid(row=3, column=1)
tile12 = Label(root, text=number).grid(row=3, column=2)

tile13 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=4, column=0)
tile14 = Button(root, text="-", command=decrement).grid(row=4, column=1)
tile15 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=4, column=2)

tile16 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=5, column=0)
tile18 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=5, column=2)

tile19 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=6, column=0)
tile20 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=6, column=1)
tile21 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=6, column=2)

tile22 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=7, column=0)
tile23 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=7, column=1)
tile24 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=7, column=2)

tile25 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=8, column=0)
tile26 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=8, column=1)
tile27 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=8, column=2)

#####################_RIGHT_HAND_SIDE_OF_GRID_########################

tile28 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=0, column=4)
tile29 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=0, column=5)
tile30 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=0, column=6)

tile31 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=1, column=4)
tile32 = Entry(root)
tile32.grid(row=1, column=5)
tile32.insert(0, "TOTAL UNITS IN STACK")
tile33 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=1, column=6)

tile34 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=2, column=4)
tile35 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=2, column=5)
tile36 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=2, column=6)

tile37 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=3, column=4)
tile38 = Entry(root)
tile38.grid(row=3, column=5)
tile38.insert(0, "TAKE PROFIT LEVEL")
tile39 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=3, column=6)

tile40 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=4, column=4)
tile41 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=4, column=5)
tile42 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=4, column=6)

tile43 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=5, column=4)
tile44 = Entry(root)
tile44.grid(row=5, column=5)
tile44.insert(0, "STOP-LOSS LEVEL")
tile45 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=5, column=6)

tile46 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=6, column=4)
tile47 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=6, column=5)
tile48 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=6, column=6)

tile49 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=7, column=4)
tile50 = Button(root, text="SUBMIT ORDER STACK", command=distance).grid(row=7, column=5)
tile51 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=7, column=6)

tile52 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=8, column=4)
tile53 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=8, column=5)
tile54 = Label(root, text="              ").grid(row=8, column=6)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please try to condense this down to a [mcve]? I doubt you need 54 labels and half a dozen functions to reproduce this problem.

Comment: You need to call `highPos = tile5.get()` and `lowPos = tile17.get()` inside `distance()` instead.